# "Change" or "Changes"

Tags: grammatical-number

Is the following sentence right or should I use **"changes"**?

> The present study aimed at quantifying the ***change***  in surface
>   air temperature and monthly total rainfall

Here, by change I meant upward/ downward trend or no trends or any other type of patterns in the distributions of temperature and rainfall

Comment: I guess the following is sentence is meaningful > The present study aimed at quantifying the **changes** in surface air
> temperature and monthly total rainfall.

Comment: Actually, I would use "changes" or "the change", not "the changes".

Comment: Are you looking for a single number or a pattern of numbers?

Comment: "the changes" is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: I would not say *the changes*. The and plurals don't play especially nice... but a more important problem is where is the verb for the main clause of this sentence (or is this just a fragment?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, as someone who has written scientific papers, I would leave it as you have it written now. Note, **none** have **the changes**.

> Projected **changes** in surface air temperature...
>   We first update our analysis of surface temperature **change** based on... (PNAS)
>   The Effects of Temperature **Changes** on Salivary Amylase Activity... (JDR)
>   Common triggers of nonallergic rhinitis are **changes** in weather and temperature (CCJM)
>   **change** in temperature, humidity, or barometric pressure or exposure to cold or dry air (CCJM)
>   ...in terms of **change** in temperature over a period of... (Scientific American)
>   Structural models in response to **change** in temperature based on ... (Nature)